# implement start and stop alarm timer android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement start and stop alarm timer in android with a repeatlist array that includes the alarm schedule conditions like everyday, year, month, dayoftheweek. I am a newbie therefore any help would be great;y appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: For the ones down-voting questions, please write a comment so that the poster knows what he or she should improve upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Please look at [link1](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Alarm) and [link2](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Hey Nik, I appreciate the help. I don't mean to be ungrateful, but could you please advise me on how to actually implement the schedule conditions like daily, dayoftheweek? This is rather tricky for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), you can set both recurring alarms and one-time alarms using that:

Comment: Thanks Stefan.Like I mentioned above, I am having tough time with the alarm schedule. Can you help?

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what your problem actually is.

Comment: Ok, I want to set the alarm schedule. Say, the alarm should go off after a week or a few hours. I need to be able to set the interval.Is this suitable?

Comment: Nik's links show that fairly well, no? :) I quickly glanced at the first one and they show how to do just that.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I apologize. I had not thoroughly gone over it. I am going to try make some implementations. Will let you know if I come undone.Thanks.